# Oracle table function on multi-layer-collection

Tags: oracle, collections, nested

I have a need for two Collection types in my program. I've made a simplified example.

```
type Trec1 is record (Tval1 number);

type Ttab1 is table of Trec1;

type Trec2 is record
(
  Tval1   number,
  Tval2   Ttab1
);

type Ttab2 is table of Trec2;
```

This Query Works fine:

```
select Max (Tval1) from table (Ttab1);
```

Whereas

```
select Max (Tval1) from table (Ttab2);
```

gives me

```
[Error] PLS-00382 (40: 44): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
[Error] ORA-22905 (40: 37): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```

I've concluded that the Collection with a nested Collection is what causes the errors. Is there any way to do table functions on this type of Collection, or should i loop through it normally?

Answer (score 1):

To be this works perfectly.

But I have created it as SQL types, not a PL/SQL type.
Added sample code for the same

**Case 1:**

```
  create type SUBTYP1 as OBJECT
  (
     AGE NUMBER,
     NAME VARCHAR2(10)
  );
  /

  create type TABLETYP1 AS TABLE OF SUBTYP1;
  /

  DECLARE
     ty1 TABLETYP1 := TABLETYP1() ;
     v_age number;
     v_name varchar2(10);

  BEGIn
     ty1.extend;
     ty1(1) :=  SUBTYP1(12,'Mahesh');

     SELECT * into v_age,v_name from TABLE(ty1);

     dbms_output.put_line(v_age||':'||v_name);

  END;
  /
```

---

**Case 2:**

```
  create or replace type SUBTYP2 as OBJECT
  (
     AGE NUMBER,
     typ1 TABLETYP1
  );
  /

   create type TABLETYP2 AS TABLE OF SUBTYP2;
  /


DECLARE
 ty2 TABLETYP2 := TABLETYP2() ;
 ty1 TABLETYP1 := TABLETYP1() ;

 v_age number;
 v_name varchar2(10);
BEGIn
 ty1.extend;
 ty1(1) :=  SUBTYP1(12,'Mahesh');

 ty2.extend;
 ty2(1) :=  SUBTYP2(14,ty1);

 SELECT AGE into v_age from TABLE(ty2);

 dbms_output.put_line(v_age);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer. I thought Oracle 12c allowed objects declared in the package spec to function like CREATE TYPE, but i guess i was misinformed.

Comment: @MelanPython I rather doubt, if my explanation is applicable for Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

What you described are PL/SQL types and they work only in PL/SQL not in SQL. So I doubt that

> select Max (Tval1) from table (Ttab1);

works fine. Can you show full creation script and output please?

If you need to have complex types returned by your query you need to create SQL collection (aka nested table) and SQL Object Type (instead of record). They are created with individual CREATE statement and they are persistent objects stored in data dictionary.

Comment: I was under the impression that Oracle 12c made it possible to declare these types in a package spec in addition to CREATE TYPE. But it seems this is only case for simple records and tables and not complex types with nested Collections. English is my 2nd language so i might have interpreted the changes in 12c to include a bit more than they do. Thanks for clarifying it for me :)